# Neon tetra left fin looks snapped and white

Tags: aquarium, fish, tetra

Hi I have 6 neon tetras in a 29-gallon tank. I noticed one of them has the left fin looking like snapped to the side and white. It swims well and eats well. No sign of discomfort from that fish. Any idea how this happened? Should I be worried and take some actions?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The fish looks ok to me, there is no discoloration, I think it should be good!

Comment: Yeah I hope it is ok..

Comment: Is it competing for food with the other tetras? Also, are there any sharp decorations, or other really aggressive fish in the aquarium? They could have had something to do with it.

Comment: It is active for food but not competing, since I feed them flake food and it will be all over the place. I have two dragon stones in the tank. Other fish are guppies, lamp-eye tetras, danios, and otocinclus.

Comment: It could have got bent on a Dragon Stone? Have you seen it using that fin?

Comment: yeah it's moving that fin like the other...